# What is __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2, NS_AVAILABLE ? Trying to use NSNumberFormatter, returns (null)

Tags: iphone, ios4, three20, nsnumberformatter

I've been having some trouble getting NSNumberFormatter to work properly.

I'm compiling in iOS4 with the Three20 Framework.

All of the NSNumberFormatter selectors require something called NS_AVAILABLE as a second parameter on the selector:

```
[numberFormatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:(NSString *)string __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2:(int)_0];
```

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with the second parameter. I've tried:

```
[numberFormatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@"," __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2:2]; // Warning: NSNumberFormatter' may not respond to '-setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2:
[numberFormatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@"," __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2:2_0]; //Error: invalid suffix "_0" on integer constant
```

and several more iterations of that.

If I don't specify the __AVAILABLE_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2 it doesn't throw a warning and compiles fine, but the selector text is black, not dark purple in Xcode as if it's not recognized.

Here's the full code snippet:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:@","];
[numberFormatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:YES];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$%@",[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:myNsNumber]]; // myNsNumber is an NSNumber with a value of 10000000
NSLog(@"numberString: %@",numberString); // numberString: (null) | instead of numberString: $10,000,000
```

I've Googled **_AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2** and **NS_AVAILABLE** with no luck.

Searching developer.apple.com only gives me the iOS 4.0 API Diffs.

Is this an issue with Three20? Does anyone know whats going on here or what NS_AVAILABLE is all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about just about everything you have in this post so far. The availability stuff lets you know what SDK the methods are included in.

This is working `NSNumberFormatter` code.

```
NSNumber *number = [UINumber numberWithInt:42];
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[nf setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *string = [nf stringFromNumber:number];
[nf release];
```

If you have a null string, then it is either because your NSNumber is null or NaN, or your format is screwed up.

Comment: OK this did work. For some reason I had to re-declare my NSNumber --> NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[myNsNumber intValue]]; Thanks.